# i would need help in installing hibernate in netbeans 14

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

Activation failed: Cannot enable Hibernate[org.netbeans.modules.hibernate] - module org.netbeans.modules.hibernate4lib/1 > 1.3

i have tried to add jar files in the module but that did not fix the problem still i can install the user plugin (hibernate)

Answer (score -1):

Just go and do everything on the add feature it will work no there on the tool